# GitHub PR Decoration is available with GitHub Enterprise only

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-api

We are using SonarQube Developer Edition Version 7.9 and GitHub (not GitHub Enterprise)

We would like to decorate our PRs with SonarQube Issues.

Does SonartQube Developer Edition supports PR decoration with GitHub.com or its work with GitHub Enterprise only?

As per documentation given at https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.2/PullRequestAnalysis.html 1 (its for older version) it seems PR decoration is only possible with GitHub Enterprise only.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/analysis/pull-request/) does include, as parameter:

> ```
> sonar.pullrequest.github.endpoint
> ```
>
> The API url for your GitHub instance.
>
> Ex.: https://api.github.com/ or https://github.company.com/api/v3/

That (`api.github.com`) means GitHub, not just GitHub enterprise (`github.company.com`).

Comment: As per documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/ no description is given for GitHub